In beamer, tikz feature "datavisualization" only works in fragile frames, why?
The following example works as soon as I uncomment the fragile option in \begin{frame}. As the error message
! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit
got an ill-formatted floating point number `'. The unreadable part was near ''
..
is somewhat cryptic (at least to me) I am asking what the error really means and why it can be resolved by using "fragile". I have so far never experienced problems when using a tikz environment within a beamer frame.
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%[fragile]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \datavisualization [scientific axes, all axes={grid}, visualize as scatter,
            x axis={label={ $x$}, max value=10}, y axis={label={ $y$ []}, min value=0}
            ]
            data {
                x, y
                0, 4.8
                1, 4.0
                2, 3.3
                3, 2.6
                4, 2.1
                5, 1.7
                6, 1.4
                7, 1.1
                8, 0.9
                9, 0.7
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Without looking too much into it: Because TikZ must change the way TeX interprets newlines in the data block that fails when that part is already tokenised (which happens for non-fragile frames). TikZ should have an option to load the data from an external file. Use that and your frame should work out without being fragile.

To expand on @Skillmon's comment:

Without looking too much into it: Because TikZ must change the way TeX interprets newlines in the data block that fails when that part is already tokenised (which happens for non-fragile frames). TikZ should have an option to load the data from an external file. Use that and your frame should work out without being fragile.

Here an example were you can see it working with an external file and without the fragile option:
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.dat}
                x, y
                0, 4.8
                1, 4.0
                2, 3.3
                3, 2.6
                4, 2.1
                5, 1.7
                6, 1.4
                7, 1.1
                8, 0.9
                9, 0.7
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%[fragile]
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \datavisualization [scientific axes, all axes={grid}, visualize as scatter,
            x axis={label={ $x$}, max value=10}, y axis={label={ $y$ []}, min value=0}
            ]
            data [read from file=test.dat];
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

